# Alternating a long running task to pause/run to reduce cpu

Tags: linux, bash, process

I have large file I need to mv and even with nice -n19 it seems to affect the server performance.

I think an option would be to run the process in "chunks" whereby I run the command for a few seconds, then sleep for a few, then resume the process.

Is there a way to do this from the command line or a better alternative ? Currently I do a Ctrl Z and fg manually.

Comment: I'd intuitively say if you resort to such tricks then chances are there is a system parameter somewhere that needs some fixing, cgroups being the first to come to my mind (though I need to figure out how). It might help to inspect what the source of congestion *really* is.

Comment: If all you do is `mv` then I believe bottleneck lies in input/output, not processor. In that case you should try `ionice`, not `nice`.

Comment: Do you really need to move it? Why not `ln -s`? Much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your performance impact is likely caused by a I/O bottleneck because `mv` does not normally require a lot of CPU cycles (unless encryption/decryption is involved). `nice` changes the scheduling priority of the task in the task list, which get to run on the CPU.

Therefore, instead of `nice`, try (for kernel > 2.6.25)

```
ionice -c3 mv <src> <dest>
```

From `ionice -h`

```
 ionice [options] <command>
   -c, --class <class>    name or number of scheduling class,
                      0: none, 1: realtime, 2: best-effort, 3: idle
```

From `man ionice`

```
 Idle   A program running with idle I/O priority will only get disk time 
        when no other program has asked for disk I/O for a defined grace 
        period.  The impact of an idle I/O process on normal system activity
        should be zero.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$command & pid=$!
while kill -STP -$pid && sleep $interval && kill -CONT -$pid && sleep $interval; do :; done
```

could do it.

Job control is really about sending these two signals (SIGSTP and SIGCONT) so this is basically job control done manually.

Comment: Depending on the sleep interval and what the process is doing, this can couse problems. For example if a network connection times out.

Comment: Ionice is undoubtedly the better solution. This simply gives the OP exactly what he was asking for.